# Return type of function determined by the function itself

Tags: c++, templates, variant

I'm trying to make a templated function which returns something based off a given function parameter, where the goal is for the function to figure out during run-time what it needs to return. Take the following code as an example:

```
// foo.h
#pragma once
class foo
{
public:
    enum type {
        ALPHA,
        BETA
    };

    enum version {
        ONE,
        TWO
    };

    foo(type t, version v) : m_type(t), m_version(v) {};

    type get_type() { return m_type; }
    version get_version() { return m_version; }

    template<typename T>
    T get_either(bool type);

private:
    type m_type;
    version m_version;
};

// foo.cpp
#include "foo.h"

template<typename T>
T foo::get_either(bool type) {
    if (type) {
        return get_type();
    }
    else {
        return get_version();
    }
}

// main.cpp
int main()
{
    foo a(foo::type::ALPHA, foo::version::ONE);

    a.get_type();
    a.get_version();

    a.get_either(true);
    ^^^^^ compiler error
}
```

This obviously fails with a compiler error, but is this even possible? For the life of me I cannot figure out how to do this, and I'm really struggling where to even begin within the world of templates.

EDIT: I probably should have explained my use-case a bit better, please see the below image. I was first trying to see if I could get it myself with a hint rather than just getting someone to figure it out for me.

[image: class diagram]

I will have a `vector` of interface classes. I would like to iterate through this list, and call `get_sensor()` to retrieve the sensor casted to the derived class. I'm doing this "manually" now by checking the `type` of the sensor and then `dynamic_cast`ing it to whatever derived class it needs to be, but I'm wondering if this can be done automatically via `variant`.

Comment: You can not have multiple functions with the same signature where only the return type is different.

Comment: Use [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)?

Comment: What's your use case? (std::variant works, or function overload as Marek R's answer.)

Comment: @Devolus Please see my updated question, this wouldn't be possible to solve with `variant` or `any`?
@Someprogrammerdude I took a look at `variant` and experimented a bit, but I'm not sure if it's possible to achieve what I want, please see my updated question.
@Unapiedra I updated my question.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the things `std::variant` and `std::any` were introduced to solve.  Templates are a compile time thing, they don't exist after the code is compiled, so there is no way to change what the type would be at run time.  `std::variant` lets you return a thing that can be one of a set of types.  `std::any` lets you return a thing that could be anything.

Answer (score 2):

You can use function overload and use an output parameter like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class foo
{
public:
    enum type {
        ALPHA,
        BETA
    };

    enum version {
        ONE,
        TWO
    };

    foo(type t, version v) : m_type(t), m_version(v) {};

    type get_type() { return m_type; }
    version get_version() { return m_version; }

    void get_either(type &t);
    void get_either(version &v);

private:
    type m_type;
    version m_version;
};


void foo::get_either(type &t) {
    t =  get_type();
}

void foo::get_either(version &v) {
    v = get_version();
}

// main.cpp
int main()
{
    foo a(foo::type::ALPHA, foo::version::ONE);

    a.get_type();
    a.get_version();

    foo::type type;
    foo::version ver;

    a.get_either(type);
    a.get_either(ver);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/P3rKW8Tsj

Answer (score 1):

You can do something similar, but as long as the parameter is compile time:

```
template<bool type>
auto foo::get_either() {
    if constexpr (type) {
        return get_type();
    }
    else {
        return get_version();
    }
}
```

Of course, this cannot work if your boolean is strictly runtime. In that case, I'd recommend using a sum type like [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).